# Equality-test std::string against char*, is operator==() always safe?

Tags: c++

Do the STL operators and overloads for `std::string` mean that it is safe to use `operator==` to compare a `char*` against a `std::string`, without restriction which is the LHS/RHS?

Comment: Short answer: [yes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not safe *without restrictions*.
The restrictions are:

- the `char*` must not be a nullpointer.
- the character sequence pointed to by the `char*` has to be zero-delimited (i.e. end with a `\0`)

But it is not important which one you put left and which one right - it gives the same result.

But there's a caveat: `std::string`s may contain `\0` characters that are not at the end. Comparing one of those against a `char*` character sequence will always give false, because the comparison will stop at the first `\0` encountered in the `char*`.

Example:

```
char c[] = "Hello\0 World!";
std::string s(c, sizeof(c));

std::cout << ((s == c) ? "ok" : "meh") << '\n';  //meh    - compares only until the first \0
std::cout << c << '\n';                          //Hello  - cout also stops at first \0
std::cout << s << '\n';                          //Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe so long as you are sure the char* is not a null pointer, and that it is null-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::string` can contain multiple null characters. However `operator==` for `std::string` and `char*` is defined as

> Compares the contents of a string with another string or a
>   null-terminated array of CharT.

Example of that problem:

```
std::string a = "hello";
char* b = "hello\0fellow\0";
bool equals = (a == b); // will give true, though a and b are not the same
```

Another issue may arise if you `char*` string is not null-terminated.